# Slow deployment of EAR on websphere 8.5

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8

I have an JAVA application EAR file, which contains EJB(3.1 annotaiton based) and WS(JAX-WS annotation based) modules. When I deploy this on weblogic it get's deployed properly without any issue, but when I try to deploy the same ear on websphere 8.5.5.0 it's not getting deployed. It gets hung in the step "Installation of MyAPp started." and doesn't move further and no errors in log as well.

The EAR doesn't have any JAR reference, all it contains is around 5 EJB and 50 web service modules(both EJB and WS has annotations). If I create the EAR with 5 EJB and 10 WS modules then it gets deployed after long time.

Is there any specific setting I need to do to get this deployed?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are running 8.5.5.0, I'd upgrade to the latest fixpack. You should also increase min and max heap size. Enable verbosegc to see, if server in not doing constant gc. Are you using built in WS engine or providing 3rd party packed in application?

Comment: Whcih fixpack you are suggesting to install? I've already increased min and max heap size and it didn't solve the issue. I am using built in WS engine.

Comment: What is your current max heap? I'd go for 8.5.5.5 for a try.

Comment: I have set min heap =1GB and max heap =4GB, where as my machine RAM =8GB

Comment: If 8.5.5.5 will not solve your issues then I'd suggest you to create a PMR in IBM support.

Comment: I will try updating to 8.5.5.5 and installing again and update here. Any link explaining updation process for 8.5.5.5?